# Show elements from base component in derived component Angular 4/5

Tags: html, angular, angular-components, angular4-forms

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-base',
  templateUrl: '<button (click)="someMethod()">Button on Base Component</button>>',
  styleUrls: ['./test-base.component.css']
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-derived',
  templateUrl: './derived.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./derived.component.css']
})

export class derivedComponent extends baseComponent implements OnInit {...}
```

Is possible to inject this button on derived HTML component?

Comment: Doesn't the first `'app-test-base'` `@Component` have a `class`?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do, also as @acdcjunior mentioned, you are missing the first component class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood what you have/want..
You can call like so:

```
<app-test-base></app-test-base>
```

on your derived.component.html page, and your app-test-base components gets started up on your derived component. Do note that the someMethod method should be declared on the app-test-base and all the other logic for interacting with that page.. You can also pass Inputs and receive Outputs from this kind of behaviour.. but thats another story :3